# Calendar software for Linux

Tags: linux, centos, calendar

I'm wondering and searching a calendar for Linux (Centos). Here calendar means to save important notes and points by date and time in all days,for this purpose I'm asking this question. Is there any possible package is there for my environment or is there any other method to full fill my requirement?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dairy - cows; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diary - journal.

Comment: whats that? Diary means `readnotebook` like that

Comment: You had written dairy all over. Please stop using code formatting for plain English, brands, etc. Code formatting's for code.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at Gina Trapani's [todo.txt](http://todotxt.com). It's a todo list you can manage using the CLI. Add search remove items, order and re-order them, use date and time stamps, and you can add @location and +subject marks. Todo.txt stores it list in a plain text file and can be read and edited with any text editor.

As you can read I am a fervent user of todo.txt. I store my todo file in my dropbox and always have this light wighted todo list in sync. Just like your question, I use this to store notes in time and use it to recapitulate all things done for some kind of topic.

You can download the [todo.sh](https://github.com/ginatrapani/todo.txt-cli/releases) as a bash script and just run it. There is no installation. Instructions and a video can be found on [todotxt.com](http://todotxt.com)

Comment: how to install this `todo.txt`

Comment: Most desktop environments have some sort of calendar application available. Your Google account has one, which you can synchronize with your Android phone's.

Comment: @user3021349 Why the markup? Not needed.